# Should I do an easy chore if an overweight parent requests it?

Tags: health-safety-shmira, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

My mom is overweight. She does most of the housework herself without help from anyone, but occasionally asks me to do an easy chore for her, such as bringing in the mail. Should I do the chore for her even though she'll lose out on a tiny bit of healthy physical activity? If I should do the chore, why? If not, why not?

<sub>Note that my rabbi holds:</sub>

- <sub>That the main commandment of honoring parents is in certain main categories, including providing [food, drink, clothing](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur143.html#3), and certain other things.</sub>
- <sub>But that I can neglect requests that aren't part of the main commandment, unless the neglect causes a parent great distress.</sub>

Comment: How can I further improve my question?

Comment: There is no basis for the question, of course you should do it. You could ask a question if they had asked for very unhealthy food, but this case is not comparable.

Comment: @ArielK what are you talking about?  The case is entirely comparable. Overweight people need to get as much exercise as possible, and refraining from ever getting up, and having their children do everything makes them more unhealthy. I've seen this happen many times.  When the children leave the house, the parents get healthier.

Comment: @avi:  Thank you for your comment.  I've edited the question to mention the fact that my mom does most of the housework herself without help.  Do you still think my case is comparable?

Comment: Even before, but especially with, the recent edit, this reads as a request for an halachic ruling for a specific case, and I've closed it in accordance with http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#questions.

Comment: @unforgettableid No, the small work doesn't really benefit her at all in that case.

Comment: -1 for trying to second-guess your mother, who as an adult can be trusted to look after her own health. Getting "as much exercise as possible" is **not** a healthy thing to do, no matter what your weight.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tshuvah that talks about this inyun(bringing food or something that does harm).The [Be'er Moshe 1:60:10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=887&st=&pgnum=179) brings down that the Chida held if if it is a danger then he should not bring it ,but if it is not good for him then he is able to. The Be'er Moshe says that he should not bring it in all cases since a father can not be mochel on his pain and can be mochel on his kovad.

I guess one can use this logic for all types of cases.

Comment: Thank you.  I've now edited my question to make it clear that my mom does the majority of the housework herself without help.  I'm not convinced that your answer applies to my newly-edited question.  :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

1. Because they do plenty of chores for the family.
2. In gratitude for all the other things that they've done for me.

Comment: What makes this answer imperfect?

Comment: There is no source you brought why you think those two reasons are reasons to listen to the overweight parent.

Comment: Sources. Or lack thereof.

Comment: We do not honor our parents because of either of those reasons! It's ONLY because HKBH commanded us so in His Torah. Period.

Comment: @MeirZirkind: Many gedolim were big on gratitude. Here's an example I found online. "Whenever Rabbi Menachem Mendel, the Kotzker Rebbe, replaced a pair of worn out shoes, he would neatly wrap up the old ones in newspaper before placing them in the trash, and he would declare, 'How can I simply toss away such a fine pair of shoes that have served me so well these past years!?'" If we can be grateful to [...] shoes [...] how much more so to human beings who [...] help us [...] out of the goodness of their hearts? --An [article](http://www.aish.com/sp/pg/48906987.html) by Dr. Alan Morinis.

Comment: Thanks for the story, but I fail to see the connection - big on gratitude does not mean the reason for the Mitzvah of Kibbud Umorah Av Voaim is because of gratitude.

Comment: @MeirZirkind:  Even if the chore turns out not to be a fulfillment of the commandment of honoring parents, maybe it's worth doing the chore just out of gratitude.  Agree?

Comment: I could agree on that

Comment: @MeirZirkind, many say part of the goal of this mitzvah is to teach hakarat hatov (gratitude) and even call it a mishpat on that basis.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen 1) Sources please? 2) The reason the chicken crossed the road was to get to the other side - his goal was to get/eat the worm; in our case, the reason we do ANY Mitzvah is because that is the will of HKBH - the REAL goal only HKBH knows (the little bit we do know doesn't give us the licence not to fulfill the Mitzvah, Shlomo Hamelech made that mistake (see Sanhedrin 21b))